# Connection issues on Team Foundation Server 2017 via SSH -- no matching mac found

Tags: ssh, tfs

We have an old OpenSSH client that we can't update. While trying to connect to the Team Foundation Ssh Service, it returns:

```
$ ssh tfs_server
no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 server hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

How can we add support for more Message Authentication Codes in TFS, so it can connect?

Comment: Did you mean you want to  access a git repo on tfs from your machine via ssh? There is no any other area to connect TFS via SSH as I know.

Comment: Try to go through this link for trouble shooting which may give you some help... [Help me troubleshoot SSH key authentication in Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-support/help-troubleshoot-ssh-key-authentication-team-foundation-server/)

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT thanks for the link. We solved the problem by insisting with SysAdmins and upgrading the OpenSSH client to 7.5.

Comment: Glad here the issue fixed, thanks for the sharing, you could move your solution to the answer, and mark it once you could, which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the SSH client from 4.3 (really old) to 7.5 solved the issue.